# Software to extract colors from images

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, gui, color

I'm looking for software that is able to extract the major colors of an image. It should basically be an alternative to the online [Color wheel by Adobe](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/) where you can upload images and extract the five main colors of an image. The software must meet these requirements:

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit
- Runs totally offline
- Actual software, not an online web app
- Extract at least five colors (more would be nice; though)
- Has a GUI interface

Preferences that are not requirements are:

- In addition to a GUI interface, it also has a command-line interface
- Able to input more than one image at a time

Comment: Related and actually inspired by this question (command line output only): [Color count sorted by occurences](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81256/color-count-sorted-by-occurences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for this assignment - I wrote a little Java application for you ;)
It fullfills all your requirements:

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit (just install a compatible Java, I recommend a 64bit version)
- Runs totally offline
- Actual software, not an online web app
- Extract at least five colors (it extracts ALL colors)
- Has a GUI interface

Things it doesn't do:

- CLI (maybe later)
- multiple images input

You can get it from: https://github.com/Zottelchen/jca/releases/latest

You can see the source code (and submit improvements) here: https://github.com/Zottelchen/jca

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great, I'll give this a shot when I get to my PC, thanks:)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's picking up the right colors for me, [here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/qtulYNl.png) of what happened when I tried using your gravatar

Comment: Now that is just... weird. I'll take a look at it, when I get home.

Comment: @Tom I just updated the tool. Seems like I am an idiot, because I created the wrong Hexcodes from the colors. (RBG instead of RGB). Please try again and tell me if it works now ;)

Comment: You're not, this application works great, +1 & accepted